is it possible to attach a pdf automatically in a file type input with react-js?
I'm trying to automatically attach a PDF to a file input in React. The PDF is rendered using pdf-react-renderer, and I want to convert it into a .pdf file and attach it to a file input. Is there a solution for this?
i try this
const [pdfBlob, setPdfBlob] = useState<Blob | null>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const generatePdfBlob = async () => {
            if (devisDetail && modal) {
                const doc = <DevisDocumentPdf devisDetail={devisDetail} />;
                const asPdf = pdf();
                asPdf.updateContainer(doc);

                try {
                    const blob = await asPdf.toBlob();
                    setPdfBlob(blob);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Erreur lors de la génération du PDF :', error);
                }
            }
        };

        generatePdfBlob();
    }, [devisDetail, modal]);


<Modal modal={modal} setModal={setModal} size={'2xl'} title={'Envoyer par email'}>
                    {pdfBlob ? (
                        <CreateEmailDevis setModal={setModal} id={id} devisDetail={devisDetail} pdfBlob={pdfBlob} />
                    ) : (
                        <div>Chargement du PDF...</div> 
                    )}
                </Modal>
            )}

<Formik
                    initialValues={{
                        email: '',
                        pdf_devis: pdfBlob ?  new File([pdfBlob], 'devis.pdf', { type: pdfBlob.type }) : null,
                    }}
                    validationSchema={SubmitFormValidation}
                    onSubmit={async (values) => {
                        let formData = new FormData();
                        formData.append('id_devis', String(id));
                        formData.append('email', values.email);
                        if (values.pdf_devis) {
                            formData.append('pdf_devis', values.pdf_devis);
                        } else {
                            console.warn('No file selected');
                        }

 <FieldInputFilePdfFormFormik
                                    id="pdf_devis"
                                    label="Fichier *"
                                    type="file"
                                    submitCount={submitCount}
                                    widthChildren="w-full"
                                    error={errors.pdf_devis}
                                    widthLabel={'w-[140px]'}
                                />


i deed it now i can attach the pdf automaticly to the input type file and i can send it but i can't see it in the form i have 'no file choosen'
